# Is there anyway check if Apple InApp auto renewable subscription has been renewed from a webapp?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I am building an IOS app with an auto-renewable subscriptions enabled. What I am attempting to do is allow a user to purchase a subscription through an in app purchase that would allow them web access as well as mobile access. However I need a way to check that a subscription in the App Store is still valid.

The Problem is that if I wait for the mobile app to initiate a purchase receipt verification then there is a chance that user with a cancelled subscription will continue to have access to  the application paid features.

The solution I am looking for is to be able to check the status of a paid subscription in the Apple AppStore from a web application. However I cannot find any documentation on how to accomplish this.

Please help.

Comment: [Verifying an Auto-renewable Subscription Receipt](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/RenewableSubscriptions/RenewableSubscriptions.html). Perhaps this will help?

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I need. Looked at Receipt Verification docs before but I had incorrectly assumed that I needed the reference to the current receipt before it can be verified.